# How to emit a socket.io event from a PHP controller?

Tags: php, sockets, events, controller, emit

I'm developping a PHP website using the Yii2 Framework and I'm trying to implement a socket.io service.

To execute socket.io I use PM2 and my file looks like this :

```
const { fstat } = require('fs');
var socket = require('socket.io'),
    express = require('express'),
    https = require('https');
    fs = require('fs');

const credentials = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('../../../ssl/keys/<path_to_cert_key.key>').toString(),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('../../../ssl/certs/<path_to_cert.crt>').toString(),
}

var app = express();
var server = https.createServer(credentials, app);
var io = socket(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: '<origin_url>',
        methods: ['POST', 'GET'],
        credentials: true
    },
    allowEIO3: true,
    secure: true
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(client){
    console.log('ok');
    client.on('test', function(data){
        console.log('test');
        console.log(data);
        io.sockets.emit('test_r', {message: 'ok'});
    });
});

server.listen(30064);
```

It runs without any error:

```
pm2 start _socket.js
```

I can easily access this socket from a view by registering javascript :

```
var socket = io.connect('<socket_url:port>', {
    withCredentials: false,
});

socket.on('test_r', function( data ) {
     console.log('it works');
});
```

It works well if I connect to the socket and emit from a view.
But the thing is that I want to emit an event from a PHP Controller or from a CoreBootstrap Object in a php function like this :

```
$emitter = new \SocketIO\Emitter( array( 'port' => '30064', 'host' => '127.0.0.1') );
$emitter->broadcast->emit( 'test', ['message' => 'test_message'] );
```

The module I'm using is ashiina/socket.io-emitter (I also tried a bunch of ohters but they did not work as well).
Nothing happens when I do this. Nothing even happens when I look at the PM2 logs.

Would someone know why the event is not emitted or if there is another way to do it ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.